# Adding BlurHandler to a composite widget in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I am have developed a composite widget like the dropdown widget found at http://showrss.info/?cs=browse.I have the widget closing and opening fine but i want to close the widget if a click event outside the widget occurs(a blur event on the widget).Currently i am sinking Blur events on the widget and overriding the onBrowserEvent method.but i dont seem to capture the event.
below is my code snippets.

```
public RichComboAutoSuggest(final Collection<String> data) {

initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
this.data = data;
initComponents();
setUiListPanelData(listPanel);
//DOM.sinkEvents(RootPanel.get().getElement(), Event.ONCLICK);
this.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK|Event.ONBLUR);

this.addDomHandler(new FocusHandler() {

  @Override public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {

    Window.alert("Blurred");
  }
}, FocusEvent.getType());


searchBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
  @Override public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
    if (searchBox.getCursorPos() > 0) {
      listPanel.clear();
      noResults.setVisible(false);
      String key = searchBox.getText();
      List<String> returnedSearch = (List<String>) RichUtils.searchForMatches(data, key);

      if (returnedSearch != null && !returnedSearch.isEmpty()) {
        for (String string : returnedSearch) {
          final Label l = new Label(string);

          l.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

              selectedValue.setText(l.getText());
              dropShadowPanel.setVisible(false);
              downArrow.setUrl("images/ddmenu_arrow.png");
              resetFields();
              listPanel.clear();
              setUiListPanelData(listPanel);
            }
          });
          listPanel.add(l);
        }
      }else{
        listPanel.clear();

        noResultsMsg.setText("No results found for \""+key+"\"");
        noResults.setVisible(true);
      }

    }else{
      listPanel.clear();
      setUiListPanelData(listPanel);
    }
  }
});


 @Override public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
int type = DOM.eventGetType(event);
switch (type) {
  case Event.ONBLUR:
    Window.alert("Blurred");
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
super.onBrowserEvent(event);
```

}

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `BlurHandler` and etc. instead of FocusHandler.